# Is it possible to create a page layout or masterpage with a common webpart zone used for all the pages in a subsite?

Tags: page-layout, custom-masterpage

I have a business need to create a page layout or masterpage in SharePoint that will have a web part zone which will stay consistant for all pages in the selected subsite.

The content in the web part zone will be updated by a site owner via the browser. Each site should use the same MasterPage and there will be a finite number of page layouts.

**For example:**

Subsite1 has 5 pages. Each of those pages need to have a web part configured to display the current events for that group.

Subsite2 has 3 pages. Each of these pages need to have a web part with static text that describes the group's mission statement.

The site owner for Subsite1 and Subsite2 would ideally update and manage this informaiton in one place as apposed to updating and configuring the content on each one of the pages.

**Question**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research and speaking with a few consultants, this exact use case is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways of partially getting your solution would be using page layouts.
Add a webpart in the page layout and configure it to display from a events list . Create separate page layouts for the subsites and events list for each subsite.

Now the pages created using the pagelayout will display the events list configured for that particular subsite.

Site owner can now work with events in the list and specify to display the view in the webpart.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this creating a individual masterpage for each to level site and then reset all the subsites to inherit the master page from the parent.

If you define the webpart directly in the master page is guaranteed that all the subpages will inherit the also the webpart.